# Simple file upload/download manager for distributing files

Tags: php, upload

I am looking for a simple, standalone file download solution in PHP for a company located in a rural area (slow internet connection) to distribute files to be downloaded by customers, press contacts, the printers', and so on, through their website which is hosted in a data center elsewhere.

**The perfect workflow would be:**

- Admin users upload files
- Admin users determine who may access the file in one of these ways:

  1. The system creates a one-time access ID for the file, **or**
  2. the system has a simple permissions management to determine (external) users who are allowed to download the file
- The program returns a URL to copy+paste into an E-Mail
- The program keeps basic track of who downloaded what (optionally)

The file size is going to range between a few kilobytes and 10-20 Megabytes maximum. File types will be PDF and JPG mostly, with an occasional high-res image or Creative Suite file.

I would probably want to make it single-sign-in capable together with the CMS that also runs on the package, so having the source code is a must, and good code readability a big plus. The server is a shared hosting package running on a LAMP stack.

Hints are much appreciated.

Comment: Is there some sort of exceptional reason you cannot use FTP + HTTP AUTH + .htaccess rules?

Comment: Yes, 1. convenience for the users - I want a graphical interface that makes uploading/downloading as simple as possible 2. additional security by being able to create "download ticket" URLs that can be disabled without having to delete the actual source file.

Comment: Search google for php file manager or download manager. That turned up tons of results. Shopping cart programs may also give you some leads. I can't recommend just one, and it will take some research to find the right one for you.

Answer (score 2):

"dl", Download Ticket Service, is a file exchange service that may fit the bill.

http://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/dl/

Comment: "dl" is a well-hidden treasure :-)